# What is Jinta and Ururu's Identity?

Tags: bleach

Jinta and Ururu are the kids that works in Urahara's shop. I'm curious as to what their identities are. As far as I remember it was never been said what their background stories are.

Are they Shinigami like Urahara was? If they were, why are they with Urahara? Were they also on the run from Soul Society?

Or are they humans with special powers like Chad and Orihime? If they are, were their powers awakened from being close to Urahara, much like Chad and Orihime's powers being awakened by being near Kurosaki Ichigo.

Or are they Quincies? Although I doubt this very much since they never been seen using bows and Quincy techniques. Or are they modified souls like Kon?

What are they?

Comment: I remember Urahara saying that Ururu is an "Anti Soul Reaper" weapon (ie anti Shinigami) in the Dub around when Ichigo fights Grimjow the first time and she was totally kicking the asses or the Arancar until i think she fell asleep. considering how strong she is i doubt she's a normal human

Comment: A point I'd like to make is that, when one of the Arrancars (He had blonde hair and arrived with Grimmjow when he goes to The World of the Living the first time) attacked Renji at Urahara's shop, Ururu was woken up by it, and the Arrancar's spiritual pressure affected Ururu. At least, that's what Jinta said. But Jinta never got affected by that Arrancar, so this confuses me. Whether this information is significant or not depends on if, later, they explain why this happens. Though, I highly doubt that they have, I will not know until I actually finish Bleach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I would like to start off by saying that their race hasn't been explicitly stated in either of the Anime/Manga, so we can only theorize what race they might be from. Most of the evidence points to them being either Enhanced Artificial Souls/Humans.**

Here are the possible theories, the facts supporting them and the facts opposing them:

---

### Theory 1: They are Enhanced Artificial Souls<sup>[1](http://www.marineford.com/Thread-Bleach-Ururu-And-Jinta-What-Are-They)</sup>

We know that [Nemu Kurotsuchi](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Nemu_Kurotsuchi) is the artificially created "daughter" of Mayuri Kurotsuchi. He used a combination of Gigai and Gikon technologies to bring her into existence. It's likely that Urahara did the same to create Ururu and Jinta.

**For:**

- They seemingly come from nowhere and live at Urahara's.
- Both have powers way above anything else a human has shown in Bleach and Ururu even has an "angry-mode" when she gets hurt.
- It shouldn't be hard for Urahara to create Mod Souls, regarding the knowledge he has about Souls, modified Souls and how they work. Someone who can create a Hogyoku can create Mod Souls for sure. Especially since Urahara didn't need to create them from scratch, as they already existed.
- For Urahara to create a special Gigai shouldn't be much of a problem either.
  He is the person who created the special Gigai that held Rukia during her two months in the human world.

**Against:**

- It's not impossible for them to be humans inspite of their strength because Inoue and Kannoji are both humans but possess abilities greater than those of normal humans.
- Unlike Nemu, they have a will of their own.

One may argue that they aren't robotic (they don't say yes to everything that Urahara says), but as Ayase points out in the comments, Kon is a Mod Soul but isn't robotic either.

---

### Theory 2: They are humans<sup>[2](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Human),[3](https://www.reddit.com/r/bleach/comments/18xgln/a_possible_explanation_of_jinta_and_ururu/)</sup>

They are said to be High-Spec Humans on the [Bleach Wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Human):

> A very small percentage of the Human population develops a high amount of Reiryoku; they are known as "High-Spec" Humans. These Humans can see and interact with Reishi-made objects, such as Souls, to varying degrees and for various reasons.

**For:**

- Urahara had the Hougyoku in his possession up until Rukia came to Karakura town and lost her powers. He lent her his special Gigai, with the Hougyoku hidden in it. They could have gained their powers from being somewhat near it. Sado and Orihime gained theirs as an indirect consequence of coming in contact with the Hogyoku, as it caused Rukia to lose most of her powers to Ichigo<sup>[Source](http://bleach.answers.wikia.com/wiki/I_read_on_Bleach_Wiki_that_the_reason_that_Rukia_lost_almost_all_her_power_to_Ichigo_was_because_of_the_Hogyoku,_but_when_she_gave_Ichigo_her_power_she_didn%27t_have_it_so_is_this_true)</sup>, which as Urahara said, was the cause of awakening of powers in Rukia and Sado. From the [Wikia article on Sado](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Yasutora_Sado):

  > Urahara then tells them that Ichigo's large amount of Reiatsu leaked onto them and that caused them to gain their powers, and that these powers are what they naturally had to begin with.
- They age like normal humans, whereas Mod Souls do not age.

**Against:**

- Given Urahara's expertise in the matter of Gigai and Mod Souls, it's possible for him to come up with a way such that Mod Souls age.
- Even though they are stated to be High-Spec Humans on the Bleach Wiki, there is no official source regarding the same.

---

### Theory 3: They are Soul Reapers

**For:**

- They always hang around with Urahara and are knowledgable about the Soul Society, Hollows, Quincies and pretty much everything a standard Soul Reaper knows, although they might have just learned about it all from Urahara.

**Against:**

- They do not have a Zanpakuto.
- They do not have any reason to live with Urahara outside the Soul Society because they aren't exiled from the Soul Society, which Urahara is.

---

### They aren't Hollows/Quincies

I say this because:

- Their physical appearance does not match with that of a Hollow, such as having a broken mask or a hollow-hole. As the [Wikia article on Hollow](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Hollow) states:

  > All Hollows wear masks, which are formed from the hearts they had lost as Humans. This mask protects the naked instinct which is left in a being after the loss of its heart, and obscures the original identity of the Hollow
- Their appearance does not match with that of a Quincy either:

  > The final point of contrast between the Quincy and Shinigami is their respective choice of uniform. While the Shinigami wear traditional, black, flowing hakama, the Quincy wear white, form-fitting, high-collared tunics. They always wear casual clothes.

  Neither do they seem to have the power to manipulate Reishi into spiritual weapons.

Comment: *"Sado and Orihime gained theirs almost immediately after coming in contact with the Hougyoku/Rukia"* i thought that Urahaha said around when the Menos first appeared (at the same time Sado's and Orihime's powers first awakened) that it was their proximity to Ichigo and his always out-flowing spiritual energy which allowed them to develop powers

Comment: @Memor-X Yeah, Urahara did say that. However, Ichigo did get his spiritual energy from Rukia, which she in turn lost (most of it) because of the Hogyoku. It's somewhat similar to [this](http://bleach.answers.wikia.com/wiki/I_read_on_Bleach_Wiki_that_the_reason_that_Rukia_lost_almost_all_her_power_to_Ichigo_was_because_of_the_Hogyoku,_but_when_she_gave_Ichigo_her_power_she_didn%27t_have_it_so_is_this_true) question, although you're right, it's not due to its direct influence. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @AshishGupta Ichigo didn't get his spiritual energy from Rukia. From the very beginning, Ichigo has always been able to see ghosts. What Rukia gave her was the power to fight as a Shinigami. He can see Hollow even before Rukia gave him her Shinigami powers. Don't forget who his parents are.

Comment: @AyaseEri From the [Wikia Page on Ichigo Kurosaki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Ichigo_Kurosaki): "Seeing Ichigo's determination to protect his family, Rukia offers to temporarily turn him into a Shinigami by piercing his chest with her Zanpakutō and transferring half of her power to him. Absorbing almost all of Rukia's power, Ichigo, making short work of the Hollow, collapses afterwards." The wiki also lists "spiritual awareness", ie the ability to sense hollows, separately. Although, if you have any edit to make, feel free to do so. It's been 3-4 years since I watched Bleach.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody really knows. There are mystery characters in Bleach and that makes it awesome for imagination and infinite possibilities and probabilities! :)

1. They are perfectly normal children… with superpowers.

I suppose it’s possible that Ururu and Jinta are just normal kids - orphans, perhaps, that Urahara kindly adopted. They do age, after all, and it’s not like we don’t have plenty of examples of humans who have super powers. There would still be a question of how they got super powers, of course - and presumably Urahara had something to do with that.

2. They are constructs.

Much more likely, to my mind, is that Ururu and Jinta are artificial children created by Urahara. This would explain their super powers, where they came from, and why Ururu has Urahara’s hair. Plus it’s Urahara. We know that he’s something of a mad scientist.

3. Jinta is normal; Ururu is a construct.

A third possibility is that only Ururu is a construct, and Jinta is a normal(ish) human kid. Ururu has done a lot more to be suspicious about - like when she fought Ichigo with so much power that he ran for his life. Or when she struck an Arrancar hard enough to make him bleed. Jinta has a bat that he can swing pretty hard, but he hasn’t done anything quite as extraordinary as Ururu. So perhaps she is the only construct.

4. They were created to fight Hollows.

Of course, whether Ururu and Jinta are constructs or whether they are humans with powers, the question still remains - why did Urahara make / empower them? One idea is that they were created as a weapon against Hollows. That would explain, for instance, why Ururu lost it when Yylfordt appeared and went into “Genocide Mode.” Because having a Hollow around made her, um, circuits react.

5. They were created to fight the Quincy.

There has been no indication that this is the case. I mention it merely because, since we are now in Bleach’s last arc, all the reveals that are going to happen need to happen in a Quincy context. So perhaps Tite Kubo has saved the reveal of Ururu’s and Jinta’s true natures because they were actually created as some sort of weapon against the Quincy. Urahara is a guy who likes to plan ahead, after all.

6. They are the shop’s defense mechanism.

Or perhaps Ururu and Jinta weren’t created to fight any specific enemy; perhaps they simply constitute the shop’s defenses. After all, what Ururu reacted to when it came to Yylfordt was his unusual spiritual pressure - a reaction that makes sense if she exists to guard the shop against hostile intruders. And for a man like Urahara, on the run from Soul Society with a shop full of dangerous (and only dubiously legal) items, having a defense team makes sense. Why he decided to make ‘em kids is an open question.

7. They are replacements for children Yoruichi and Urahara couldn’t have.

This, at least, is the theory that the anon sent me along with the request. Apparently one theory is that Yoruichi either had a miscarriage or simply couldn’t have children, and so Urahara created these replacements. I have my doubts about this one, insofar as it seems dangerously shippy for Bleach (a canon couple with both characters living? What?), and also Yoruichi has shown no particular affection for the two kids. But it’s a possibility.

8. They are mod souls.

Now that Ururu and Jinta have aged, this may be unlikely but hey. Maybe Gigais that age are a thing now. After all, we’ve so far had only one mod soul in canon - Kon. And what we know about the mod souls is that they were created to fight, and they were given specific offensive powers (Kon’s seems to be “kicking”). Kon himself came from Urahara’s shop - from a box of “defective” merchandise. So if Urahara had one mod soul, why not more? Perhaps Ururu and Jinta are both mod souls that Urahara rescued, and that explains their powers to fight Hollows.

9. They were created by the Hogyoku.

We’ve seen new life created in a couple of ways in Bleach. There’s Kurotsuchi’s creation of Nemu, which seems to be tied to whatever the hell Kurotsuchi is, and there was Aizen’s creation of Wonderweiss, through the Hogyoku. Well, we know that Urahara also had the Hogyoku for a while, and we know that the Hogyoku manifests desires. So perhaps Urahara said to himself, “Man, I wish I had a couple of kids who happened to be awesome at fighting Hollows” and the Hogyoku took care of the rest.

10. Tessai created them.

Or perhaps I am way off base to think that Urahara created them at all. There is another guy in the shop, after all, and Tessai’s abilities are as mysterious as his past. All we know is that he’s a genius with Kido, and he works with Urahara. Maybe he’s the guy who created Ururu and Jinta, using his Kido experience. Can Kido even be used that way? Probably not....

And I saw a cool theory that Ururu and Jinta are mod souls based off Rukia and Renji, and then placed in a Gigai which slowly bonds with the soul inside it. Rukia's Gigai was going to turn her into a human if she was left in it long enough, which explains why Ururu and Jinta age like humans.
Them having totally different personalities from Renji and Rukia is weird, but look at Nemu and Mayuri.

Comment: Last paragraph reminds me of Ururu and Rukia's bangs.

Comment: Number nine and number ten are pretty logical. I could go for one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe Jinta is Urahara's kid and Ururu is a Gikon and Gigai mix (construct) like Nemu. I also agree that Ururu may have been created as a defense system for Urahara's shop. Either that or Ururu was created to protect and befriend Jinta. Jinta's bat is mentioned in the manga and I think it's called something like his "indestructible iron bat". It's possible that Tessai or Urahara gave it to him to protect himself.

This theory also leaves the question of who Jinta's mom would be. The first person that comes to mind would be Yoruichi, but he bears no physical resemblance to her. Then again, it is also possible that Jinta is a construct made from Urahara's DNA, due to his physical resemblance to Urahara.

Answer (score 0):

They are gikai's fitted with artificial souls.

Kisuke is a master gikai maker. They aren't human and they have not aged in the series..
To put simple they are weapons.

Ergo why they can fly and have crazy strength.  The girl was the first prototype and the boy came 3 years after.

Answer (score -1):

There's a part before the Arrancars appear that Rukia has both Jinta and Ururu with her, telling Orihime that she and Renji have a secret. She never gets to finish because something happens.

To be honest, I'm convinced they are the offspring of Rukia and Renji, but soul reapers aren't allowed to have relations when in the court guard squads, let alone have children.

So, my answer is that they are Rukia and Renji's kids.

Comment: the part about Court Guard Squad Members not allowed to have offspring needs citation since it contradicts the end of the Manga where we see Rukia's and Renji's daughter

Comment: I think you might be referring to a doujinshi. AFAIK, Jinta and Ururu was never said to be children of Rukia and Renji.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, they are human. Possibly augmented by Kisuke's Benihime Zanpakuto. Benihime has the ability to deconstruct and reconstruct anything to fit Kisuke's needs.

Alternatively, they are/were fullbring children abandoned for their terrifying powers and left to fend for themselves. Possibly stumbling into a situation where they crossed paths with Kisuke through petty theft or accidentally breaking part of the shop in a battle with a strong hollow.

Answer (score -2):

My answer is he saved both of their lives, probably the same way Rukia awakened Ichigo's powers, and most likely the Hogyoku was used as well because those 2 know all about it. I'm assuming they're wizards.