# How old are Ururu and Jinta?

Tags: bleach

Just wonder from beginning, Ururu and Jinta are looks like a child. But as we know they're also have some super strength as a human and a child.

So, how old exactly they're before and after time skip? Are their age ever mentioned in anime or manga?

Comment: You might want to read this, http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27552/what-is-jinta-and-ururus-identity

Comment: @AyaseEri So, are they still debated as a human?

Comment: They haven't show up in the manga lately, so there is no additional information on them.